# como sumar celdas de todas las paginas con datatable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

Necesito sumar todas las celdas de una columna de Datatable, he probado varias formas pero aun no he logrado conseguir que funcione, lo mas cercano ha sido:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= nume1; i++) {
                        total += Number(todos.rows[i].cells[5].innerHTML); 
}
```

pero solo suma las celdas de la columna 5 de la página actual y lo que quiero es sumar  en todas las páginas.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head> 
<body>
    <style>
        .hideButton {
            display: none !important;
        }
    </style>

    <div id="efectivo">
        <table id="todos" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">
            <div class="contenedor2">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><button style="border: none; border-radius: 100%;" class="mdl-button--primary mdl-button--raised vercolum">
                            <i class="material-icons iconover">&#xE5D2;</i>                                  
                        </button>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <button class="boton_ocultar_mostrardet">
                                    <i>Locación</i>                                   
                                </button>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <button class="boton_ocultar_mostrardet">
                                    <i>Nombre dispensadora</i>                                   
                                </button>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <button class="boton_ocultar_mostrardet">
                                    <i>Serial</i>                                   
                                </button>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <button class="boton_ocultar_mostrardet">
                                    <i>Producto</i>                                   
                                </button>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <button class="boton_ocultar_mostrardet">
                                    <i>Selección</i>                                   
                                </button>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <button class="boton_ocultar_mostrardet">
                                    <i>Valor</i>                                   
                                </button>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <button class="boton_ocultar_mostrardet">
                                    <i>Costo</i>                                   
                                </button>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <button class="boton_ocultar_mostrardet">
                                    <i>Tipo de entrega</i>                                   
                                </button>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <button class="boton_ocultar_mostrardet">
                                    <i>Fecha</i>                                   
                                </button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <thead style="width: 100px;">
                <tr>
                    <th>Locación</th>                                                                    
                    <th>Nombre dispensadora</th>
                    <th>Serial</th>
                    <th>Producto</th>
                    <th>Selección</th>
                    <th>Valor</th>
                    <th>Costo</th>                        
                    <th>Tipo de entrega</th>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Locación</th>                                                                    
                    <th>Nombre dispensadora</th>
                    <th>Serial</th>
                    <th>Producto</th>
                    <th>Selección</th>
                    <th>Valor</th>
                    <th>Costo</th>                        
                    <th>Tipo de entrega</th>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody> 
                <?php
                require_once '../ConsultasSW/DetalleTodosSW.php';
                echo DetalleTodos($_POST["v1"], $_POST['v2'], $_POST['v3'], $_POST['v4']);

                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table id="cons" class="mdl-cell--1-offset" style="width: 80%; border-collapse: collapse; margin-top: 10px; text-align: center">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="padding: 10px; width: 200px;">Cantidad de productos</th> 
                    <th style="width: 200px">Valor total</th> 
                    <!--<th style="width: 200px">Costo total</th>--> 
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody style="border-top: 1px solid">
                <tr>
                    <td id="can"></td>
                    <td id="tot"></td>
                    <!--<td id="cos"></td>-->
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var nume; 
            var total = 0; 


             nume = $('#todos> tbody> tr').length;  //obtiene la cantidad de filas
             total = 0;



            for (var i = 1; i <= nume; i++) {
                total += Number(todos.rows[i].cells[5].innerHTML);

            }
            $("#can").html(nume);
            $("#tot").html(total);


            $('#todos tfoot th').each(function () {
                var title = $(this).text();
                $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="BUSCAR" />');
            });

            //inicia dataTable
            var table = $('#todos').DataTable({
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: 'XLS',
                        extend: 'excelHtml5',
                        className: 'Exportardetalle hideButton',
                        title: 'detallado TODOS',
                        extension: '.xls',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'print',
                        className: 'Imprimirdetalle hideButton',
                        title: 'detallado TODOS para ' + nombreCliente,
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible'
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "scrollY": scroll,
                "scrollX": true,
                "pageLength": alto,
                "responsive": true,
                "order": [[8, "desc"]],
                "autoWidth": true,
                "language": idioma_español,
                "pagingType": "full_numbers"

            });

            //detecta cuando de ha escrito en los input de columna y realiza filtro
            table.columns().every(function () {
                var that = this;


                $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
                    if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                        that
                                .search(this.value)
                                .draw();
                    }
                    totales();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function totales() {
            var total = 0;


            var nume1 = $("#todos").DataTable().rows( {search:'applied'} ).nodes().length;

            var nume2 = $('#todos> tbody> tr> td').length;

            if(nume1 >= 1 && nume2 > 1){
                //suma las filas totales para las columnas seleccionadas 
                for (var i = 1; i <= nume1; i++) {
                    total += Number(todos.rows[i].cells[5].innerHTML); 
                alert (total);

            }
            }  
            $("#can").html(nume1);
            $("#tot").html(total);

        }
    </script>
    <script src="js/FuncionesJS.js"></script>  
</body>
```

el problema es cuando se llama a la funcion totales, en esta se suman las celdas correspondientes a la columna 5 de las filas que estan en la pagina mostrada del datatable y lo que requiero es que se sumes las celdas en todas las paginas, tanto la que se muestra como las que estan ocultas...

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida csjo a  SOes y te invito a que hagas una visita por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Añade el código de como generas  tu datatable.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, ya he subido el codigo de como se genera el datatable.... @bercklynCarlosviza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la función rows para acceder a todas tus filas del objeto DataTable y a data para todos los datos indistintamente de en que página estes. Es decir:

```
var total = 0;
$('#todos').DataTable().rows().data().each(function(el, index){
  //Asumiendo que es la columna 5 de cada fila la que quieres agregar a la sumatoria
  total += el[5];
});
console.log(total);
```

Comment: gracias por responder @Dariel Ramos Díaz de Villegas    implemente la solucion que propones mostrando el resultado en alguna parte de la pantalla, y lo que muestra es algo como   0100010001000100010001000, osea que si hay 8 filas que en la celda 5 tienen un valor de 1000 me muestra 8 veces 1000 pero no la sumatoria de las columnas "8000", que puedo hacer para que solo muestre la sumatoria????

Comment: intenta con poner total += parseInt(el[5]);

Comment: Esta perfecto asi, muchas gracias @Dariel Ramos Díaz de Villegas

Comment: OKOK me alegro. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Otra manera es utilizando el callback [footerCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/footerCallback)

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "pageLength": 4,
        "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
        
            total = this.api()
                .column(1)//numero de columna a sumar
                //.column(1, {page: 'current'})//para sumar solo la pagina actual
                .data()
                .reduce(function (a, b) {
                    return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
                }, 0 );

            $(this.api().column(1).footer()).html(total);
            
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Valor</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Prueba</td>
                <td>10</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prueba</td>
                <td>20</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prueba</td>
                <td>30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prueba</td>
                <td>40</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prueba</td>
                <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prueba</td>
                <td>60</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prueba</td>
                <td>70</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prueba</td>
                <td>80</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prueba</td>
                <td>90</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Total:</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: Si hubiera Prueba1 y Prueba2 como podria sumar por ejemplo solo de prueba1 por un lado y prueba2 por otro

Answer (score 1):

Para recorrer los elementos de un DataTableJS lo mejor es usar la funcion de [iterator()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/iterator()), ya que este lo hace independientemente si tiene paginación o no, o cualquier configuración de tu tabla.

```
function getTblTotal() {
    let total = 0,
        todos = $("#todos").Datatable();
    todos.rows().iterator('row', function (context, index) {
        let node = $(this.row(index).node());
        total += +(node.find('td').eq(5))
    });
    return total;
}
```